# Rails link_to pass param across to popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I plan to add many diners to a restaurant however I require passing the ID of the restaurant selected, to the form of the new diner (which I hope to have in a popup window).

how do I make a new diner while storing the restaurant to the diner?

I can store the current_user to the diner in the controller using

```
@diner.user = current_user
```

however I also want to store the particular chosen restaurant to the diner as well

```
@diner.restaurant_id = params[:restaurant_id]
```

I have for the link_to on the show page of the restaurant

```
<%= link_to 'New Diner', new_diner_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

I'm unsure how to pass the id of the restaurant to the link_to in order to use it in the following diner form.

Please note: a single user can have many restaurants and I store the user id in the diner table so that I not only know which user added the diner but also which restaurant the diner belonged to and since the user may have more than one restaurant but wishes to see all diners across all restaurants that is why I store the user id in the diner table.

Comment: nevermind fixed it with `new_diner_path(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id), :class => 'btn btn-primary' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
<%= link_to 'New Diner', new_diner_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'New Diner', new_diner_path(restaurant_id: @restaurant.id), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

you should then have params[:restaurant_id] available in your next action

Comment: yeah just figured that one out but thanks heaps for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

nevermind fixed it with

```
    <%= link_to 'New Diner', 
new_diner_path(:restaurant_id => @restaurant.id), 
:class => 'btn btn-primary'  %>
```